# Continuously differentiable implies Lipschitz in one variable?

Tags: numerical-methods, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:[t_{0}-a,t_{0}+a] \times [y_{0}-b,y_{0}+b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. Consider the problem

$$\begin{align*} y' &= f(t,y),\\
y(t_{0})&=y_{0}.
\end{align*}$$

Assume that the solution to the initial value problem exists in the interval $[t_{0}-a,t_{0}+a]$. Prove that Euler's method converges.

I have a theorem that will give convergence if I can establish that
$$ |w_{i}-y(t_{i})| \le \frac{hM}{2L} \left(e^{L(t_{i}-a)}-1\right),$$
where $y_{i}$ is the true solution, $w_{i}$ is the approximation from Euler's method, $M$ is a bound on $|y''(t)|$ and $L$ is the Lipschitz constant for $f$ in the variable $y$.

I can obtain $M$ from the fact that $f$ has a continuous derivative on a compact set, but I am having trouble determining if $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in $y$.

How can I show that $f$ is Lipschitz in $y$?

Comment: What is the question? You already wrote all the answers. (Except that the solution might not reach the time boundary if $L$ is too large.)

Comment: To see the Lipschitz property, use the mean value theorem and the extreme value theorem.